# Competitive Programmer’s Handbook, Longest increasing subsequence - explanation needed

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I'm having hard time understanding a part of above mentioned topic.

> Our ﬁrst problem is to ﬁnd the longest increasing subsequence in an array of n elements. This is a maximum-length sequence of array elements that goes from left to right, and each element in the sequence is larger than the previous element. For example, in the array
>
> `{6,2,5,1,7,4,8,3}`
>
> the longest increasing subsequence contains 4 elements:
>
> **2**,**5**,**7**,**8**

> Let length(k) denote the length of the longest increasing subsequence that endsatposition k. Thus,if we calculate all values of **length(k)** where **0≤k≤n−1**, we will ﬁnd out the length of the longest increasing subsequence. For example, the values of the function for the above **array** are as follows:
>
> **`length(0) = 1`**
>
> **`length(1) = 1`**
>
> **`length(2) = 2`**
>
> **`length(3) = 1`**
>
> **`ength(4) = 3`**
>
> **`length(5) = 2`**
>
> **`length(6) = 4`**
>
> **`length(7) = 2`**

The part that i don't understand is why if for some **k**, **length(k) = c** then why is it possible for some **n>k** to have
**length(n)<length(k)**, the array that we choose does only extend in right direction, so I think the **length(k)** as k increases **can't** decrease because we are only getting new values
What am I missing? Please help.

Comment: `length[k]` corresponds to the maximum length of a subsequence that ends at exactly position `k`, and not before.

Comment: So you mean that k-th element of an array **has** to be included in a sequence?

Comment: Not exactly. I mean that the sequences concerned by `lenght[k]` end at kth position

Comment: Yup, that's what I meant, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Let length(k) denote the length of the longest increasing subsequence
> that **ends** at position k.

So, for example, **length(3)** = 1, because the value at that position is `1`, so there are no any smaller numbers in the array to the left of it.